# How to track the crypto payment made to specified address on ethereum?

Tags: web3js, web3j, exchanges

I have created different ethereum wallet address for each user registred on exchange .
Now the problem is user can deposit crypto at any time and we have to reflect the balance in user account and there is not only one crypto but 20 other tokens too . If average ethereum transaction is 100000 per day so i have to check every time the receiver is our user wallet address it will increase the consumption of database because out of 100000 only 1 or 2 it made to our exchange created wallet address .

What should i do ?

Should i create our own rpc node or use existing third party services?

Best way to check for receiver payment detection ?

Thanks

Comment: you can subscribe to a specific event let say `Transfer`, by using a filter you can get only the transactions from a specific erc20 token for a specific address as receiver etc.

Comment: But what if I have 10,000 receiver address then subscribing to each event with different token addresse lets say 20 different token . How other exchanges manage this ?

Comment: I don't know how they do, but I guess there must be reading the balances and saving them on a DB, and updating this DB based on events.

Comment: It can be updated when user load the page

Comment: There must be something because there are thousand of exchanges working and they all must have this deposit functionality .From where they found this way of depositing and tracking payment ? because I have been researching about this from weeks and found nothing .

Comment: I don't understand what is your concern?

Comment: My conern is i want to keep track of receiver address whenever any crypto deposited in it

Comment: again you can do it by subscribing to `Transfer` event

Comment: Yes but what if I have 20 30 tokens and 10000 wallet address It won't be an easy task

Comment: Do i need to create my own RPC node for each blockchain

Answer (score 1):

Build an event monitor and filter every event to see if it matches the involved addresses.

You can run it after every block or periodically, you can even filter them by using the topics parameter.
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth.html#getpastlogs

You can optionally use subscribe to get all the logs as push instead of polling
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-subscribe.html#id16

You need a single node and a single RPC connection.

It's a pretty intensive process, I recommend you run it in a local network/small testnet first.